# Unable to install passenger module

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nginx, passenger

I am trying to configure the passenger and Nginx for rails application .

I am getting compilation error while execute the passenger command.

**Ruby version :**
ruby 2.3.1p112 (2016-04-26 revision 54768) [x86_64-linux]

**Rails version**
Rails 4.2.6

**Error message:-**

```
# passenger-install-nginx-module
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/specification.rb:2158:in `method_missing': undefined method `this' for #<Gem::Specification:0x7cab3c passenger-5.0.28> (NoMethodError)
        from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1057:in `find_active_stub_by_path'
        from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:64:in `require'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/passenger-5.0.28/bin/passenger-install-nginx-module:33:in `<top (required)>'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/bin/passenger-install-nginx-module:23:in `load'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/bin/passenger-install-nginx-module:23:in `<main>'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
```

could you please help me on this matter.

Comment: Did you get this working? I'm using ruby 2.3.0 and having the same problem.

Comment: I'm seeing the same problem (same exact ruby/rails version)

Answer (score 2):

If not resolved yet, you can try:

> gem update --system

and then try to compile again.

Answer (score 1):

This works in my case:

Remove ruby and rvm - then Reinstall. Try again.